# How to add a new config to putty?

Tags: putty

I want to add a new config logfile_size to putty beacuse  I find some logs are too big to openwhen I use putty. It will create a new log_file when the old log were bigger than the config.

I find that all configs are defind in the putty.h,CONFIG_OPTIONS.So I add a new config to it like this

`X(INT, NONE, logfilesize)`

and then I use  `conf_set_int()`, `conf_get_int()`(these funtion are given by putty  to get the config)   to using this config,but it has no effect.

So has I miss  some important thing?  How to add a new config to putty?